# Could not read memory at: 28, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299

Tags: python, cheat-engine

***i get this error when i try to acces to location in memory****

> From Get Pointer:: Could not read memory at: 28, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299

> From Get Incress Suns:: Could not read memory at: 0, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299

```
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *

class Offsets:
    sunsOffsets = [0x48, 0x5C, 0x1C, 0xE0, 0x4, 0x5560]


class Menu:
    def __init__(self) -> None:    
        self.application = 'popcapgame1.exe'
        try:
            self.mem = Pymem(self.application)
            self.module = module_from_name(self.mem.process_handle, self.application).lpBaseOfDll
        except Exception as error:
            print('From Init:: {0}'.format(error))

    def appInfo(self):
        print('Address Of ( {0} ):: {1}'.format(self.application,self.mem.base_address))
        print('Module:: {0}'.format(self.module))

    def incressSunCount(self):
        try:
            baseAddress = (self.module + 0x000A0C78)
            address = self.getPointerAddress(baseAddress, Offsets.sunsOffsets)
            self.mem.write_int(address, self.mem.read_int(address) + 100)
        except Exception as error:
            print('From Get Incress Suns:: {}'.format(error))
    
    def getPointerAddress(self, base, offsets):
        try:
            addr = self.mem.read_int(base)
            for offset in offsets:
                if offset != offsets[-1]:
                    addr = self.mem.read_int(addr + offset)
            addr += offsets[-1]
        except Exception as error:
            print('From Get Pointer:: {}'.format(error))
        return addr
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu = Menu()
    menu.appInfo()
    menu.incressSunCount()
```

[image]

Comment: When I was finding the Pointer Paths it was taking a long time so After some minutes Stop it And I Have Get Some Paths , I Think The Problem Here.  but when i make It To get all Paths (i do not stop it ) The Code Work